# Grub: cant boot Ubuntu HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have a dual boot, W10 and Ubuntu 16.04. Each OS is installed on a HDD.
Very often, when I quit Ubuntu or update W10, my GRUB partition is erased and I have to use boot-repair to make things back together.

Today I had the same problem after shutting down Ubuntu (properly), but there was no update from W10 nor Ubuntu. After rebooting my computer, I only had a GRUB shell. I used boot repair as usual, but now My only option in GRUB is :

```
EFI/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
EFI/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
System Setup
```

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5enDn.jpg)

When I choose first option, nothing happen.
When I choose second option, a blue screen  named `Shim EFI key management` ask me if I want to perform a MOK management.

My boot is UEFI.
I added a boot sequence for `EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi` and even `EFI/ubuntu/grub.efi`, but all I got is the same 2 options

Comment: May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/  Windows is known to not add back logical partitions to partition table if Windows is installed in BIOS boot mode on MBR drives. But have not seen issue on UEFI/gpt?

Comment: I've already tried with this method https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info And the result is the same as the iso of boot-repair

Comment: Boot-Repair cannot fix everything, I was asking for the Summary Report it gives. Just post link to that report which has many details on your configuration.

Comment: here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/hgxZJn2hwq/

Comment: after this last boot repair, I can see my ubuntu in grub, but now i'm stuck on a black screen with :
`/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, XXX/XXXx files, XXX/XXXX blocks`

Comment: i did `sudo apt-get purge nvidia-*` and now i can finally boot ubuntu. But that kind of issue often happen ! At least on my vm I could do snapshot

Comment: You should be backing up. discussion of alternatives/strategy backups
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2368992&p=13677224#post13677224 & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryBackupRecovery
& http://askubuntu.com/questions/2596/comparison-of-backup-tools Did you install correct nVidia driver for your system? From Ubuntu repository, not from nVidia directly?

Comment: Yes the first thing I did was to perform a backup with deja dup. I am using acronis true image on windows. It seems i cannot do incremental backup with deja dup, only full backup.
For the drivers, I didn't install the nvidia driver this time, I'll use the default intel hd driver i guess